# Adding history support to my ajax script

Tags: ajax, history

I'm trying to load my next/previous posts links with ajax. I've written this piece of code, and it works well. However, when the user clicks the 'Back' button, the location in the address bar is not updated.

```
$(".next a").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#portfolio_item").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " #portfolio_item");
    $("#portfolio_item").animate({marginLeft:'98%'});
    $("#portfolio_item").animate({marginLeft:'0px'});
    $("#right_content, #gallery").fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

I've read about plugins like 'jquery address' and 'bbq', but how can I apply them to my code? Hoping for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you need some URL edit + history management (without loading a new page) you should checkout [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). This is an awesome js library that allows you to rewrite your URL without reloading a page and storing your history in JavaScript variables.

In order to see how it works there is a downloadable demo and a tutorial on the first link I gave you.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've seen that plugin as well, how ever I stumbled upon this one: http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/. I've got it to work, only the location is displayed wrong: http://websites.nl/portfolio/#/http://websites.nl/portfolio/item1. Any idea how I can change that without breaking the functionality?

Comment: I guess you want your url to have only item1 after the #/. When you pass your new url, are you putting "item1" or "/item1" ? This might be the problem (I never used your plugin).